# How to make a video stream published with FMS available from 2 different urls (on the same domain)

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, apache, video-streaming, flash-media-server

I'm publishing a multibitrate stream with adobe live media encoder to flash media server and i have to duplicate it to two different urls within one domain. 
Maybe it's possible by configuring apache or maybe there's another way. 
Any help'd be appreciated.
Thx in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone needs this info:

 * create a folder in `Flash Media Server 4\applications` (i called it `1`) and copy all files from `Flash Media Server 4\applications\live` there.

 * in `Flash Media Server 4\applications\live\main.asc` (if there's no such file - copy one from `Flash Media Server 4\samples\applications\live`) add the following code:
 + to `application.onAppStart = function()`:

```
conn = new NetConnection();
conn.connect("rtmp://server_ip/1");//ip/new application folder name
```

```
application.onPublish = function (clientObj, streamObj){
    trace("got a stream : " + streamObj.name);
    if(conn.isConnected){
        ns = new NetStream(conn);
        ns.attach(streamObj);
        ns.publish(streamObj.name);
        trace("publishing through other app");
    }else{
        trace("connection not ready");
    }
}
```